# remote logging with rsyslog and separting imcoming log messages by strings

Tags: linux, logging

i have setup remote logging with rsyslog. On the logging target is installed rsyslog 8.2102.0-2+deb11u1.

I want to separate the recived log messages by IP and strings. I tried this:

if ($FROMHOST-IP == '10.100.100.5') and ($msg contains 'ntpd') then
{ action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/remote/10.100.100.5/ntpd.log") }

The above setting does not work.

This one works.
if ($FROMHOST-IP == '10.100.100.5') then
{ action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/remote/10.100.100.5/ntpd.log") }

I have tried many combination but was not able to get it to work.
Is there any hint how to get this to work? What am i doing wrong?

Best regards!